# Linking Data from Listbox to Label in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, label

Please help me. What I'm trying to do is to transfer the selected item from the listbox into a label. But every time I click an item from the listbox, it doesn't work.
Here is the code.

```
Private Sub lbClients_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)     
            Handles lbClients.SelectedIndexChanged

      For i = 0 To lbClients.SelectedItems.Count -1
           Label1.Text &= lbClients.SelectedItems.Item(i).ToString() & " "
      Next


End Sub
```

I've included a photo of the error.

[This is what it looks like. The one with the Client name label.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urPhb.png)

Please help me. I know that it is not that hard. But I've been searching for answers and it's still like that. I'm just new to vb.net, I'm sorry. And thank you.

Here is the code for what I used to fill the listbox.

```
Private Sub ListBoxClients()
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=EURIZZE-PC;Initial Catalog=INTERTRANS;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim SQLDA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM CLIENTS", connection)
    Dim dt As New DataTable


    connection.Open()
    SQLDA.Fill(dt)
    lbClients.DataSource = dt
    lbClients.ValueMember = "User_"
    lbClients.DisplayMember = "Clientname"
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `ListBox` contains items of type `DataRowView`. Can you show a code how `ListBox` was filled? `lbClients.SelectedItems.Item(i).ToString()` will execute `DataRowView.ToString()`

Comment: @Fabio I have edited my post and put the code for what you requested :(

Comment: You can use [`GetItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the text representation of the specified item. This way you don't need know anything about the data source or display member of the list box and the list box answers your request.

Answer (score 0):

ListBox.SelectedItems returns a collection of the currently selected items.

Loop through the SelectedItems collection of the listbox.

For example code:

```
Dim text As String = ""

For Each item As System.Data.DataRowView In lbClients.SelectedItems
    text &= item.Row.Field(Of String)(0) & ", "
Next
Label1.Text = text
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your ListBox is bounded to the DataTable and using `DisplayMember` to show items.
In this case item is of type `DataRowView` - that is why you get type names in the label, you need to specify which column you will use as text for selected items in the label.
DataRowView have property `.Row` which return underlying `DataRow` object.
Using value of `lbClients.DisplayMember` must show same text as items in ListBox

```vb
Dim text As New StringBuilder()
For Each item As DataRowView in lbClients.SelectedItems
    text.Append(item.Row.Field(Of String)(lbClients.DisplayMember))
    text.Append(" ")
End For
Label1.Text = text.ToString()
```

Creating strings in loops will be more efficent with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. But I got an error. It says: "Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'." What does that mean? :(

Comment: It mean that column you trying to cast containing type `Integer`. Check value of `DisplayMember` it must contain name of column `Clientname`. Or use `item.Row(lbClients.DisplayMember).ToString()` - then you will see is right column used as text